# i cant use append in command doscord py

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

im new to python and i want to make a simple bot
i want to get names from user and ad them to a list
but i cant use list methods in @bot.commad

my code:

```
@bot.command(pass_context=True)
async def add(ctx,*args):
    tempP = [*args]
    for el in tempP:
        players.append(tempP[el])
    await ctx.send('{} players: {}'.format(len(players), ', '.join(players)))
```

and traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 83, in wrapped
    ret = await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "c:\Users\MREZ\poll\bot.py", line 17, in add
    players.add(tempP[el])
AttributeError: 'Command' object has no attribute 'add'
```

ps: i can use `players = [*args]` byt i lose pervious elements from players list.

Comment: The error message shows different code from the code you showed us. Make sure the .py file is saved, restart Python and the bot and try again.

Comment: i want to say i used both of 'add' and 'append' but didn't work

Comment: "i can use players = [*args] byt i lose pervious elements from players list." The error message clearly tells you that `players` is **not a list** when the code reaches this point. Probably this is because it got replaced with a `Command` somewhere else in your code that you aren't showing us. This sort of thing is one of the cautions against using global variables.

Answer (score 0):

Try using append instead of add, since I am assuming this is a list.
line 17:

```
players.append(tempP[el])
```